# What do you call it when one does something (may be committedly) but actually because it is instructed by a book

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

What do you call it when you do something (may be committedly) because it is instructed by a book (divine book). When an outsider looks at it, it feels that the act is for lack of word "spiritually empty" or something of that sort.

Example: If a person goes to a temple or a church just because he is instructed to do it by a book. Would it be mechanical

He goes to do prayers. But it feels too _______ (mechanical ?)

Comment: Literally ***lip service*** (and synonyms listed in your fav thesaurus).

Comment: You might also consider **perfunctory**, one of whose meanings, according to _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ is "characterized by  routine or superficiality: MECHANICAL." Yet another option is **pro forma**, meaning "for [the sake of] form"—originally a Latin phrase, but now thoroughly incorporated into standard English.

Answer (score 1):

The word I would use there is **rote**. From [TFD online](https://thefreedictionaryonline.com/rote):

> **rote** 1  *n.*
>   1. A memorizing process using routine or repetition, often without full attention or comprehension: learn by rote.
>   2. Mechanical routine.

Usage 2 seems exactly what you're asking for, as in "He did it by rote," or "It was a rote observance."